# How to adb chmod 750 on /sdcard using batch

Tags: shell, unix, adb, file-permissions

I am learning adb. Can someone please tell me why below chmod command isn't changing permissions on the dir on /sdcard? *It works fine in /data,* but I'm trying to test in /sdcard. Thanks for any help.

```
adb shell su -c "chmod -R 750 /sdcard/path/to/dir"
```

Current perms are `-rw- --- ---`

I am running command from a batch script.

I am rooted and assume I don't need the su with sdcard, but have tried the following and they don't work either.

- adb chmod -R 750 /sdcard/path/to/dir
- chmod -R 750 /sdcard/path/to/dir
- adb shell "chmod -R 750 /sdcard/path/to/dir"

Comment: This has nothing to do with BATCH FILES - Batch files are text-based scripts that are executed by the command processor (typically COMMAND.COM on DOS and earlier versions of Windows, cmd.exe on OS/2 and later version of Windows). The tag batch-file can be used for programming-related problems in writing a batch script file for a Windows-based operating system.

Comment: I am using it in a DOS batch file and thought I should say that. I'm not entering command in CMD window.

Comment: su and chmod are unix commands. Your question has nothing to do with Windows. I understand it's in a bat file, but it's a unix question.

Comment: +1 for 1. trying to solve your own problem and 2. documenting in your question what you've done. BUT, you're mixing apples (so to speak) and oranges. Windows .bat files don't know anything about `chmod`. You need to be running a consistent set of commands, either file access utilities from Windows with a .bat file or unix file utilities from a shell script (usually `bash`). I'm sorry, but I'm not certain what Windows commands (if any) give similar functionality to `chmod`. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter Yes, I'm running this in a DOS batch file in windows. I do several adb things this way: adb devices, wait-for-device, kill and start server, push and pull. This particular command works in /data, but not /sdcard. As you see, got kicked out of batch-file. Hoping some adb, android, or unix person can look at command and see problem.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I am rooted. The folder contains lockscreen images. There's an anomaly with my device such that if i change permissions (say 600 to 750) it affects cycling of the lockscreen images. I'm trying to track down what's going on, but want to test in /sdcard before /data

Comment: What file system is the containing partition formatted as? Some file systems (e.g. FAT) don't support changing modes.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I don't know. Device is android. Aren't all android partitions the same? I'll check this out. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a device nearby to check, but I would expect a removable SD card to be formatted FAT. A virtual SD card (internal flash) wouldn't need to be, but it wouldn't surprise me if the OS formatted it as FAT anyway.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Windows only tells me that file system is "generic hierarchical". I will test on /data and try to keep damage to minumum :) Thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This generally won't work. Android sdcard volume is normally mounted with "-noexec" flag to prevent exactly what you want to do from happening, no matter what FS type (vfat or ext2/3/4) it is.

Since you have a rooted device, you may want to try remount sdcard volume without noexec flag - not sure if it work with FUSE filesystem drivers, though…

Comment: Conferring with someone knowing more, I concluded this. Thanks for the explanation! can you give me syntax for "-noexec"? I use this to gain access /data: adb -d shell su -c "mount -o remount rw, /data. Would I use *adb -d shell su -c "mount -noexec remount rw, /sdcard*?

Comment: @user338032 "mount -o remount,rw" should just do, no need to add "-noexec".

Answer (score -2):

I know I'm almost a year late to the party, but try using:

```
adb shell su -c chmod 750 /sdcard/path/to/dir/*
```

The little wildcard at the end will apply the permissions to every file in the folder.

You could also use something like:

```
adb shell su -c chmod 750 /sdcard/path/to/dir/*.apk
```

...to only apply the permissions to APK files in the directory.

Comment: That's not what the user is trying to do.